# Look for pattern in a line and print following values in the brackets

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract some info from a file. The file has many lines like the one below

```
"names":["DNSCR"],"actual_names":["RADIO_R"],"castime":[2,4,6,8,10] ......
```

I want to search in each line for names and castime, if found I want to print the value in the brackets
the values in the brackets are changing in different line. for example in the above line names is DNSCR, and casttime is 2,3,6,8. but the length might
be different in next line

I have tried the following code but it will always give me 10 characters but I only need whatever in the bracket only.

```
c_req = 10 
keyword = ['"names":','"castime":']

with open('mylogfile.log') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        for key in keywords:
            left,sep,right = line.partition(key)

            if sep: 

                    print key + " = " + (right[:c_req])
```

Comment: Does the file contains inconsistent quotation marks (as in your example)?

Comment: The file actually has consistent quotations. wrong copy from my side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks just like json, are there brackets around each line?
if so, the whole content is trivial to parse:

```
import json
test = '{"names":["DNSCR"],"actual_names":["RADIO_R"],"castime":[2,4,6,8,10]}'
result = json.loads(test)   
print(result["names"], result["castime"])
```

You could also use a library like pandas to read the whole file into a dataframe if it matches a whole JSON file.

Comment: No there are no brackets around each line. The lines are actually very long with no specific pattern, what I show here is what I'm interesting in.

Comment: It would help if you could show the entire structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use Regular Expression:

```
import re

# should contain all lines
lines = ['"names":["DNSCR"],"actual_names":["RADIO_R"],"castime":[2,4,6,8,10]']

# more efficient in large files
names_pattern = re.compile('"names":\["(\w+)"\]')
castime_pattern = re.compile('"castime":\[(.+)\],?')

names, castimes = list(), list()

for line in lines:
    names.append(re.search(names_pattern, line).group(1))
    castimes.append(
        [int(num) for num in re.search(castime_pattern, line).group(1).split(',')]
    )
```

add exception handling and file opening/reading

Answer (score 0):

Given `mylogfile.log`:

```
"names":["DNSCR"],"actual_names":["RADIO_R"],"castime":[2,4,6,8,10]
"names":["FOO", "BAR"],"actual_names":["RADIO_R"],"castime":[1, 2, 3]
```

Using regular expressions and [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

```
import ast
import re

keywords = ['"names":', '"castime":']
keywords_name = ['names', 'castime']

d = {}

with open('mylogfile.log') as searchfile:
    for i, line in enumerate(searchfile):
        d['line ' + str(i)] = {}
        for key, key_name in zip(keywords, keywords_name):
            d['line ' + str(i)][key_name] = ast.literal_eval(re.search(key + '\[(.*?)\]', line).group(1))
print(d)

#{   'line 0': {'castime': (2, 4, 6, 8, 10), 'names': 'DNSCR'},
#    'line 1': {'castime': (1, 2, 3), 'names': ('FOO', 'BAR')}}
```

`re.search(key + '\[(.*?)\]', line).group(1)` will catch everything that is in between `[]` after your `keys`.

And `ast.literal_eval()` will transform remove usless quote and spaces in your `string` and automatically create `tuples` when needed.

I also used `enumerate` to keep track of which lines it gets in the log file.